# EU Blue Card travel validity after leaving country for good

Tags: eu, indian-citizens, blue-card

I (Indian Citizen) was working in France on EU Blue card from Nov 2016 - Oct 2017 and then I left France for good but I still have my EU Blue card with me which expires in Nov 2019. My question is can I use this card for travel in Schengen?